# parsing xml with BeautifulSoup: multiple tags with same name - how to find the right ID

Tags: python, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have some xml:

```
<sporsmal_liste>
    <sporsmal>
        <versjon>1.0</versjon>
        <besvart_av>
            <versjon>1.0</versjon>
            <doedsdato>0001-01-01T00:00:00</doedsdato>
            <etternavn>Giske</etternavn>
            <foedselsdato>1966-11-07T00:00:00</foedselsdato>
            <fornavn>Trond</fornavn>
            <id>TG</id>
            <kjoenn>mann</kjoenn>
        </besvart_av>
       <besvart_av_minister_id>NHD</besvart_av_minister_id>
       <besvart_av_minister_tittel>nærings- og handelsministeren</besvart_av_minister_tittel>
       <besvart_dato>2010-10-11T00:00:00</besvart_dato>
       <besvart_pa_vegne_av i:nil="true"/>
       <besvart_pa_vegne_av_minister_id i:nil="true"/>
       <besvart_pa_vegne_av_minister_tittel i:nil="true"/>
       <datert_dato>2010-09-30T00:00:00</datert_dato>
       <emne_liste/>
       <flyttet_til>ikke_spesifisert</flyttet_til>
       <fremsatt_av_annen i:nil="true"/>
       <id>47703</id>
       <rette_vedkommende i:nil="true"/>
       <rette_vedkommende_minister_id i:nil="true"/>
       <rette_vedkommende_minister_tittel i:nil="true"/>
       <sendt_dato>2010-10-01T00:00:00</sendt_dato>
       <sesjon_id>2009-2010</sesjon_id>
       <sporsmal_fra>
           <versjon>1.0</versjon>
           <doedsdato>0001-01-01T00:00:00</doedsdato>
           <etternavn>Nørve</etternavn>
           <foedselsdato>1951-03-29T00:00:00</foedselsdato>
           <fornavn>Elisabeth Røbekk</fornavn>
           <id>ELN</id>
           <kjoenn>kvinne</kjoenn>
           <fylke>
               <versjon>1.0</versjon>
               <id>MR</id>
               <navn>Møre og Romsdal</navn>
          </fylke>
          <parti>
              <versjon>1.0</versjon>
              <id>H</id>
              <navn>Høyre</navn>
          </parti>
     </sporsmal_fra>
     <sporsmal_nummer>1808</sporsmal_nummer>
     <sporsmal_til>
         <versjon>1.0</versjon>
         <doedsdato>0001-01-01T00:00:00</doedsdato>
         <etternavn>Giske</etternavn>
         <foedselsdato>1966-11-07T00:00:00</foedselsdato>
         <fornavn>Trond</fornavn>
         <id>TG</id>
         <kjoenn>mann</kjoenn>
     </sporsmal_til>
     <sporsmal_til_minister_id>NHD</sporsmal_til_minister_id>
     <sporsmal_til_minister_tittel>nærings- og handelsministeren</sporsmal_til_minister_tittel>
     <status>besvart</status>
     <tittel>Jeg viser til ... [longer text a have shortend..]</tittel>
     <type>skriftlig_sporsmal</type>
</sporsmal>
<sporsmal>   ... another sporsmal (question) </sporsmal>
<sporsmal> en the next one.... </sporsmal>
..more of these..
</sporsmal_liste>
```

I have up until now I have handled this with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content) # where r.content is the xml (result from requests.get(url))

for question in soup.find_all('sporsmal'):
    # to get the id of the person this is a question to (sporsmal_til) I would:
    print question.sporsmal_fra.id.text
```

this works. it returns **ELN**,  the id of the person who asked the question. The problem is with the id of the item itself (< sporsmal >), it is **47703**, but I cant' seem to get it "the normal way":

```
for question in soup.find_all('sporsmal'):
    print question.id.text  #this returns **TG**
```

and 'TG' should be the result of

```
question.besvart_av.id.text 
# answered by
```

or

```
question.sporsmal_til.id.text 
# question for
# it's the same dude that is asked to answer, and who answers the question
```

and it is. both these return **TG** but:

```
question.id.text
```

should return **47703**, but it doesn't. 
(or how else can I get the id 47703?)

So what am I doing wrong here?

PS: since the xml I have here might be some-what confusing to a non-Norwegian, I have edited and chosen other fields with less confusing names in  my examples.

Comment: Your first code snippet has `question.sporsmal_til.id.text` which should be `TG`. Are you sure `question.id.text` is not returning 47703?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. `question.id.text` returns u'TG', u'EGS' and so forth. (e.g. the first id in the elemens <sporsmal>, but the first is in a child-node (besvart_av), and not the ID I'm looking for.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I learnt something from this question. When you do `soup.<something>`, unlike what you expect, it's a recursive call. And that's why it gives you the ID "TG", as recursively it's the first one to be encountered.

So from what I understood, you can do a search on the same level like this:

```
>>> for q in soup.find_all("sporsmal"):
...     print q.find("id", recursive=False).text
... 
47703
>>> for q in soup.find_all("sporsmal"):
...     print q.find("id", recursive=True).text
... 
TG
>>> for q in soup.find_all("sporsmal"):
...     print q.find("id").text # By default, the recursive call is true.
... 
TG
```

Some reasons why I think it's recursive:

```
>>> soup.id
<id>TG</id>
```

If it wasn't recursive then the following would fail as `sporsmal` has no child with the tag `kjoenn`. This proves it is recursive.

```
>>> soup.sporsmal.kjoenn
<kjoenn>mann</kjoenn>
```

Comment: No it doesn't do a recursive call - that's the whole point of having structure.

Comment: It does a recursive call in the subtree you specify.

Comment: Yes but he is only doing a find_all() for the `<sporsmal>` tag, not `id`, and when you put a tag name after a dot, the point is to only search within the immediate children.

Comment: yeah, so I am still unsure about the dot notation to parse a tree, but I think this is what is happening. `question.id` gives him the first <id> in the subtree.

Comment: I am trying to research that now.

Comment: I think the fact that it appears "recursive" is because it wasn't parsed properly - because it's trying to parse it assuming HTML. It sees all these non-HTML tags it doesn't recognize, and makes everything into some kind of flat hierarchy. BeautifulSoup's dot operator is not recursive in general, try it on true HTML data.

Comment: And BTW, sporsmal DOES have a child named versjon ... its first child in fact.

Comment: I'd be interested to see if you can get BeautifulSoup to parse this as XML - I haven't had luck so far and need to step out for a bit. Take a look at my current answer to see how to do this (and why).

Comment: Oh my bad, I missed that child.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11246/discussion-between-varunl-and-ansari)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the first issue: You're using the HTML parser to parse XML. Since this is not well-defined HTML, it is getting confused about the structure. To [parse XML with BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-xml), you need to install lxml, and initialize the soup like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "xml")
```

However, there is at least one more issue since this isn't parsing it properly either. Will update if I figure it out.

Comment: I've done this now, and while it doesn't in i self solve the problem, I appreciate the correction.